# How to make underscore method available in view and controller in rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

There is `underscore` method in `ActiveSupport::Inflector` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-underscore). But it is not available in both erb view and rails controller. How can we make it available in view or in rails controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is added to String.  You should be able to call it on any String object, in any context (controller, view, etc.) assuming you've loaded ActiveSupport

Comment: Your post reminds me: added .to_s before underscore and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rails 4 you should do the following

1. go to the controler then follow this example:

   def new

   @about = About.new

   @delete_me = 'EggsAndHam'.underscore

   end

you can call the @delete_me on your view

Comment: let me know if it helps you. Active support should already be added. Hey, if this work for you, RANK ME UP